# Euclidean distance for area inside multiple polygons using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst

I am trying to create a Euclidean Distance grid for numerous land parcels across a region (vector polygon layer). The conceptual diagram below shows the region in grey and land parcels in white.

I need to calculate Euclidean Distance for the area inside (not between) the polygons (i.e. the white area for polygons A, B, C).

[image: 'Conceptual diagram showing the region in grey and land parcels in white.']

I am using ArcGIS Pro (Advanced with Spatial Analyst), so far my workflow is:

- Start with two polygon layers 'land parcels' (white) and the 'region' (grey)
- [Erase tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/erase.htm) to subtract the 'land parcel polygons' from the 'region polygon'. This results in a layer with 'donut polygons'
- [Euclidean distance tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/euclidean-distance.htm)  with the 'donut polygon' layer above as the 'Input raster or feature source data'.

While the method above worked on one occasion, I cannot seem to repeat this. The issue is that I get Euclidean Distance between polygon (i.e. for the grey area, and not for the white area for polygons A, B, C).

**Are there any suggestions to change my workflow or alternate approaches?** I have looked at [Calculate Euclidean distance to raster WITHIN multiple polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130146/calculate-euclidean-distance-to-raster-within-multiple-polygons), however it is different to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this workflow:

1. Create a copy of your polygon dataset converting the polygons to lines, you can use the [Feature to Line tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-line.htm)
2. Run the Euclidean distance tool on your polyline layer and set the environment setting [Mask](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/mask.htm) to the original polygon layer.